# superfish menu styling issue

Tags: css, superfish

Im trying to style my superfish menu in my Wordpress theme. Im trying to elimate the gap between the dropdown when on hover.

As you can see from the picture there is a small gap.

I have tried to edit the below code which i believe is applicable to the section in question. However when applying a negative margin its making the options overlap as shown.

[image]

Im currently editting the below code:-

```
.sf-menu li li {
background:     #193030;
}
```

however placing a margin-top: -10px; produces this:-

[image]

Your help and advice is appreciated.

thanks

**EDIT**

Please see full CSS of superfish :)

```
/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
margin:         0;
padding:        0;
list-style:     none;
}
.sf-menu {
line-height:    1.0;
}
.sf-menu ul {
position:       absolute;
top:            -999em;
width:          10em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below)     */
}
.sf-menu ul li {
width:          100%;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
visibility:     inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
float:          left;
position:       relative;
}
.sf-menu a {
    display:        block;
position:       relative;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
left:           0;
top:            2.5em; /* match top ul list item height */
z-index:        99;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
top:            -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
left:           10em; /* match ul width */
top:            -10;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
top:            -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
left:           10em; /* match ul width */
top:            0;
}

/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.sf-menu {
float:          left;
margin-bottom:  1em;
}
.sf-menu a {
border-right:   1px solid #193030;  
padding:        .75em 1em;
text-decoration:none;
font: 11.5px Open Sans;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
color:          #fff;
}
.sf-menu li {
background:     transparent;
}
.sf-menu li a {color: #fff;}

.sf-menu li li {
background:     #193030;
margin-top: -0px;
}
.sf-menu li li a:hover {background-color: #0a1c1c;}
.sf-menu li li li {
background:     #9AAEDB;
}
.sf-menu li:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover,
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
background:     #193030;
outline:        0;
}

/*** arrows **/
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
padding-right:  2.25em;
min-width:      1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately     */
}
.sf-sub-indicator {
position:       absolute;
display:        block;
right:          .75em;
top:            1.5em; /* IE6 only */
width:          10px;
height:         10px;
text-indent:    -999em;
overflow:       hidden;
background:     url('images/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
}
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
top:            1.0em;
background-position: 0 -100px; /* use translucent arrow for modern browsers*/
}
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px -100px; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}

/* point right for anchors in subs */
.sf-menu ul .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  -10px 0; }
.sf-menu ul a > .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  0 0; }
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.sf-menu ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}

/*** shadows for all but IE6 ***/
.sf-shadow ul {
background: url('../images/shadow.png') no-repeat bottom right;
padding: 0 8px 9px 0;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 17px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 17px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
}
.sf-shadow ul.sf-shadow-off {
background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Can we see an example of the code? Not everyone knows how a Superfish menu is built ;)

Comment: Hi Kyle, apologise, i will place the full code ;)

Comment: Can you re-create the problem in JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi Andrew, i will attempt to however the site above shows the problem, as in the gap within the menu and the children from it. Give me half hour :)

Comment: Hi Andrew, http://jsfiddle.net/rusticblonde/zMaGM/1/... its not REALLY working properly though :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this has now been fixed thanks to the [lovely Florian..](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6767168#6767168)

I needed to amend

```
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
    left:           0;
    top:            2.1em; /* match top ul list item height */
    z-index:        99;
}
```

This stated how far the UL was from the top.

I hope this knowledge helps others too.

Comment: yea, sorry i just copied the actual part of the CSS :)